# Detecting typed date with native datepicker in Chrome

Tags: javascript

How do you detect when the user has written a date in Chrome?

I tried using the change event, but that triggers too often. 
When you click in the year field to write a new year, it triggers on the first character and select the year "0002"[image]

To reproduce it use this code:

`<form>
  <input type="date" id="theDate" onchange="alert('onchange event fired');" />
</form>`

Then choose a date and click on the year and start writing a year.

I tried using blur to see when the date input lost focus and the user was done typing the date. The problem with this is that it does not detect when a user uses the date-picker to choose a date. Then the change event is fired, but not blur.

**Edit:**
To make things clear: What I would like to achieve is the same functionality as when using the jQuery UI date-picker in other browsers.

There you get the change event when the user leaves the field after writing the date manually. 
If the user chooses a date using the date-picker the focus is automatically lost and the change event is triggered.

It seems unnecessary to have to leave the field after having used the date-picker.

Comment: If you want to wait until the user finished typing, use onblur

Comment: The problem is that onblur is not raised when the user uses the datepicker to choose a date, then the change event is raised.

Comment: When I change the date and leave, it throws the onblur as expected. see http://jsfiddle.net/qqx9o222/1/

Comment: While I can't help you here. The story about this bug in chrome is quite intersting. The chrome developer, who implements input widgets, does not understand what the spec means with "commit action". I discussed it with him and he refused to fix it for all input types. At the same time the FF team implemented input type range (the right way and requested to add an example to the spec for type="range"). After that the chrome developer fixed this issue partially for type="range" and again refused to fix it for other input types. Please help and also open a chrome bug.

Comment: Here is the part of the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#common-input-element-events

Comment: @alexanderfarkas can you link to relevant bug reports in Chrome?